# Import-vApp throwin Line 157: Duplicate element 'AddressOnParent' error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to deploy an OVA file using powershell script. I found a script from internet and modified it a little bit and execute. During execution at Import-VApp command i am seeing this error: Import-VApp Line 157: Duplicate element 'AddressOnParent'.

I am able to deploy the OVA manually. But thru this script, i am seeing this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Please find my powershell script below. (keeping only important script below, per suggestion).

```
param(
    )
    #---- Custom OVA Properties ::> START <:: ----- #
    $vAPPPropertyId_ip4enable = "IPv4 Enable"
    $vAPP_ip4enable = "True"
    $vAPPPropertyId_ip4address = "IPv4 Address"
    $vAPP_ip4address = "10.51.98.20"
    $vAPPPropertyId_ip4netmask = "IPv4 Netmask"
    $vAPP_ip4netmask = "255.255.255.0"
    $vAPPPropertyId_ip4gateway = "Ipv4 Gateway"
    $vAPP_ip4gateway = "10.51.98.1"
    $vAPPPropertyId_ip6enable = "Ipv6 Enable"
    $vAPP_ip6enable = "False"
    #$vAPPPropertyId_ip6address = "IPv6 Address"
    #$vAPP_ip6address = ""
    #$vAPPPropertyId_ip6gateway = "IPv6 Gateway"
    #$vAPP_ip6gateway = ""
    $vAPP_defaultRouteKey = 1
    $vAPP_defaultRouteCmd = ""
    #---- Custom OVA Properties ::> END <:: ----- #

    $rp = Get-ResourcePool -name $resourcePool
    Write-Host " Resoure Pool = $rp"

    $cluster = $rp.ExtensionData.Owner
    $vhost = (Get-Cluster -Id $cluster).ExtensionData.Host[0]
    Write-Host " VHost = $vhost "
    $VMHost = Get-VMHost -Id $vhost 
    Write-Host " VMHost = $VMHost "

    if ($PortProfile -ne "") 
    {$PortgroupId = Get-VirtualPortGroup -Name $PortProfile -Distributed -VMHost (Get-VMHost $VMHost)}

    Write-host "PortGroup = $PortgroupId"

    Write-Host "Importing VApp .... "

    $ovalocation = "C:\Script\s42700x8_1_1_a2.ova"

    Write-Host "vAppName = $vAppName"

    $vms = Import-VApp -Source $ovalocation -Name $vAppName   -VMHost $VMHost #-Location $rp -Datastore $ds
    #$vms = Import-VApp -Source $ovalocation -Name $vAppName -Location $rp  -VMHost $VMHost -Datastore $ds

    }

    finally {
      disconnect-VIServer -Confirm:$false
    }
```

**Output looks like this:**

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\Script\OvaTestFile2.ps1
9/22/2014 3:23:58 AM    Import-VApp     Line 157: Duplicate element 'AddressOnParent'.
```

Comment: Go to the line 157, inspect it(or comment it out) and try to figure out what is going wrong. It is never a good idea to post **257 lines** of a script, edit it down to the pertinent lines and more SO community is more likely to help.

Comment: Thank you Raf. Reduced the code to the important piece in the post. The powershell code does not have anything in Line 157. Any clue how to debug the .ova file?

Comment: Remove comments and empty lines, run the script again and you shall get the line you are looking for.